# Schengen visa application help

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, egyptian-citizens

In the Schengen application, there is a question which asks:

> Entry permit for the final country of residence where applicable issued by....valid from ... until ...

I am applying from Egypt. I am planning to visit the UK and then Germany. I already have a UK visa and I am applying now for a Schengen visa to be able to travel from the UK to Germany.

Regarding the above question, shall I write:

> Issued by British Embassy in Cairo valid from date issued until date expiration?

Comment: Are you planning to return to the UK after Germany or to Egypt? What is your residence status there and your nationality?

Comment: I am Egyptian and will be in the Uk with a tourist visa i will travel to Uk for 20 days and i will go to German in that period for 7 days

Comment: The UK is not your "final country of residence" then, is it?  It seems they're asking for evidence of your permission to stay in the country where you will end your trip.  If that country is Egypt and you are traveling with an Egyptian passport then the question does not apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

> 28. Entry Permit for Your Final Destination Country, ***If Applicable***
>
> Write the number and validity dates for your visa at your final destination, if this country is outside the Schengen area.

***If Applicable*** means that you only have to answer this question if it concerns you; so write nothing, just leave it blank. For example, if you reversed your journey, travelling first from Egypt to Germany, and then went on to the UK, you would include your UK visa information. For your itinerary, Egypt-UK-Germany-Egypt, your final destination is your home country (and you don't need a visa for it).